# How do I get my navbar to work on cellphones because the burger menu is not opening

Tags: html, navbar, bootstrap-5, hamburger-menu

my navbar does not work on mobile phones.
Could you help me understand what I should do?
Here is the menu code:

```
    <!-- Navbar Start -->
<div class="container-fluid p-0">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark py-2 py-lg-0 px-lg-5">
        <a href="https://jobcool.fr" title="Travail sans diplôme" class="navbar-brand d-block d-lg-none">
            <p class="m-0 display-4 text-uppercase text-primary">ripeur<br>balayeur<span class="text-white font-weight-normal"></span></p>
        </a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between px-0 px-lg-3" id="navbarCollapse">
            <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto py-0">
                <a href="https://jobcool.fr" title="La sécurité financière dans un travail sans diplôme" class="nav-item nav-link"> GARDIEN</a>
                <a href="https://jobcool.fr/emploi-bien-paye-sans-diplome.html" title="La sécurité financière dans un travail bien payé sans diplôme" class="nav-item nav-link"> EXPLORATEUR</a>
                <a href="https://jobcool.fr/trouver-un-boulot-a-vie-sans-diplome-et-sans-experience-en-devenant-fonctionnaire-en-ile-de-france-a-la-mairie-de-paris.html" title="La sécurité financière dans un travail sans diplôme" class="nav-item nav-link"> RIPEUR</a>
                <a href="https://jobcool.fr/travailler-sans-diplome-en-devenant-garagiste-a-la-mairie-de-paris.html" title="Travail bien payé sans diplôme" class="nav-item nav-link"> MÉCANICIEN</a>
                <a href="https://jobcool.fr/travailler-sans-diplome-en-devenant-conducteur-a-la-mairie-de-paris.html" title="La sécurité financière dans un travail bien payé sans diplôme" class="nav-item nav-link"> CONDUCTEUR</a>
                <a href="https://jobcool.fr/Travailler-dans-la-nature-sans-diplome-en-ayant-la-securite-financiere.html" title="La sécurité financière dans un travail sans diplôme" class="nav-item nav-link">⚰️ FOSSOYEUR</a>
                <a href="https://jobcool.fr/Travailler-dans-la-nature-en-etant-fonctionnaire-a-la-mairie-de-paris.html" title="Travail bien payé sans diplôme" class="nav-item nav-link"> NETTOYEUR</a>
                <a href="https://jobcool.fr/travailler-sans-diplome-et-sans-experience-dans-les-ecoles-et-les-colleges-de-la-mairie-de-paris.html" title="La sécurité financière dans un travail sans diplôme" class="nav-item nav-link"> COLLÈGES</a>
                <a href="https://jobcool.fr/travailler-en-creche-avec-des-enfants-sans-diplome-ni-experience-a-la-mairie-de-paris.html" title="La sécurité financière dans un travail sans diplôme" class="nav-item nav-link"> CRÈCHES</a>
                </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
<!-- Navbar End -->
```

Comment: Please be clear and what you are trying to do, how and what you are precisely expecting

Comment: ok, i'll try to be more clear.
When I look at my site from a mobile phone, the burger menu does not work.
I'm trying to figure out how I can make it work. The website is jobcool.fr

Comment: I already added some tags, but it seems you are using bootstrap 5. You don't mention any of this in your question. How are people going to guess what you want? This is not a bootstrap only die site. Also don't add information in the comments, as not everybody reads that. Edit the question. Of you want people to help you, help them help you.

Comment: Check if you're missing the bootstrap js :  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: Thanks Fork. i have write the bootstrap code on my index page but it's alxays the same thing: the burger menu doesn't open...

Comment: I think it's not caused by the code you show, but by other, more fundamental  technical problems with the website. I can't inspect the website from my mobile, but I put it on some online tools, and they reported some errors. You should debug everything